# Custom timeline for View-Animation?

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to be able to create an arbitrary input for *time* into a standard [Android animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). Instead of an animation running for 1 second, I want for instance the input to be a coordinate from user touch input. This way I could for instance create a circle motion of object A when the position in the circular motion is defined by a linear input on slide A.

Crude illustration:

[image: Illustration]

Now I'm thinking this could be achieved with defining the translation animation in XML just as with regular animations under /res/anim, but overriding the time input to come from a user input control instead. It minght also be done with a custom interpolator, I'm not sure. I don't what a set start and end time of the animation, in any case.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

edit: To further answer a couple of the comments: Think if it as the user slides/drags the blue dot. No interpolation between the input occurs. As soon as the user lifts the finger, the "animation" stops.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVGg4zPRHNE

Comment: animations are dependent on time, you cannot "stop" time unless you invented a Time Machine ;)

Comment: Is this an actual animation? I.E. is something moving on it's own? Or does the red circle only move when the blue circle move - in which case it's just rigging and no animation should be involved.

Comment: @nitzanj only moving when the blue circle move. Nothing happens unless the user acts. What do you mean "rigging"? psink: This should also answer your objection.

Comment: you shouldn't use animations for this, use a custom View or custom Drawable instaed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need some sort of 'rigging' - Defining a movement of one element as a function of another. In your case this function needs to transform the the linear position into a circular position.
There is no animation involved - When the user moves the blue circle, the red one is moved accordingly.

You should register for callbacks for the blue circle movement (i.e. onTouchEvent, or a seekBar's on change, depending on how you implement your 'bar'). Then you calculate the new position of the red circle and then you put it there.

Here's a simple working example of a custom view that draws two circles according to a given percentValue. I tested using s simple SeekBar and it works:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    private int centerX = 0;
    private int centerY = 0;
    private int radius = 0;
    private final int handleRadius = 25;

    private final Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint handlePaint = new Paint();
    private float percentValue = 0f;

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        handlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    // Call this whenever the value of that linear bar is changed - so when the user moves his finger etc.
    public void setValue(float percentage) {
        this.percentValue = percentage;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // this is the main circle
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, circlePaint);

        // calculate the angle based on the percentage of the linear movement (substracting (pi/2)     so the zero value is on top)
        double angle = (percentValue / 100) * (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI / 2;

        // sin and cos to calculate the position of the smaller circle - the 'handle'
        float handleX = centerX + (float) (radius * Math.cos(angle));
        float handleY = centerY + (float) (radius * Math.sin(angle));

        // drawing the circle
        canvas.drawCircle(handleX, handleY, handleRadius, handlePaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // choose whatever values you want here, based on the view's size:
        centerX = w / 2;
        centerY = h / 2;
        radius = w / 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is if I could leverage some of the animation code from the sdk, I wouldn't have to do all the math and myself. There's already code there for rotating abd translating. I'll accept this if no simpler solution pops ut though

Comment: @Nilzor you can simplify that by using a RotateDrawable, see `setLevel` method that rotates your Drawable

Comment: You can probably avoid some of the calculations if you don't want to do them yourselves, but you won't end up with simpler or shorter code - The entire 'math' here is only 3 short lines.

Comment: Cool, this solution paired with rotateDrawable will solve my specific use case (which is a bit more complicated than the example I illustrated in the question)